# Rust. Как использовать математику в типе String

Tags: rust

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я делаю проект в котором присутствует ввод данных с клавиатуры, а также else if. Проблема в том что с клавиатуры выводится тип String, но этот тип не подходит для математических операциях. Подскажите как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Выполняйте преобразование в тип, который поддерживает интересующие вас математические операции. Пример преобразования есть сразу же во второй главе книги https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```rust
let some_string = String::from("12");  // например, такая строка

let number = some_string.parse::<i32>();

match number {
    Ok(result) => println!("Получилось, число: {:?}", result),
    Err(_) =>     eprintln!("Строка - не число"),
}
```

Строкой

```rust
let number = some_string.parse::<i32>();
```

мы парсим строку и переделываем её в `i32` (можете поставить здесь любой челочисленный тип, который вам нужен), тогда `number` получит тип `Result<f32, std::num::ParseFloatError>`.

В строках

```rust
match number {
    Ok(result) => println!("Получилось, число: {:?}", result),
    Err(_) =>     eprintln!("Строка - не число"),
}
```

проверяем, что преобразование прошло успешно, и, если получилось, выводим `Получилось, число: <ПОЛУЧИВШЕЕСЯ ЧИСЛО>`, если же нет, выводим `Строка - не число` в стандартный поток ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите оперировать с данными с клавиатуры как с числами, преобразуйте их в число:

```
let my_int: i32 = my_string.parse().unwrap();
```

Загляните [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043268/convert-a-string-to-int) за деталями.